# Different versions of AIR and Flash being used in release and debug

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am making a few HTTP/HTTPS requests to my servers from an Adobe Air application. While monitoring the network traffic (using Fiddler web debugger), I noticed that when debugging, a different version of Air and flash were being used than when the installed application (production) is executed.

Here's are the differences:-

```
**Production**
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/17.0
x-flash-version: 17,0,0,128

**Debug - adt**
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/3.1
x-flash-version: 11,1,102,58
```

How can I ensure to be running the application with the same version of AIR and flash while debugging, because the difference in environments is a cause of concern.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have the "same environment" as production while debugging because you need the debug content and the debugger to debug!

Answer (score 0):

you can target specific flash players with compiler options... like swf-version=17

[Here are the docs about using the options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ee0.html)

Answer (score 0):

What IDE do you use? In both cases do you start application on iphone or in simulator? I suppose It just means you have two different AIR runtimes installed in you system, one - production, another one comes with your IDE and AIR SDK for debugging. Answer how to renew you IDE AIR, depends on what IDE do you use.

Comment: I use Flash Builder 4.6. How do I upgrade AIR and flash runtime for my IDE? I do perform the usual upgrades to AIR runtime and flash player; thought that's what the IDE will use too!

Comment: I think it may be not possible for 4.6 version, you should use 4.7. And try this instructions http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=5810 (for 4.7) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083822/how-do-i-upgrade-flash-builder-4-6-to-air-3-4 (for 4.6 and I suppose it works only for old versions of AIR)